# Remove thin grey border on jquery item slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to remove the grey border around my item.Please find the jsfiddle result about here: http://jsfiddle.net/LdCnK/embedded/result/

and the coding here:
http://jsfiddle.net/LdCnK/

The main slider display html links:

```
<div id="mi-slider" class="mi-slider">
<ul>
<li>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="center">

<a href="http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=by74Vpim1DE&offerid=249405.176558&type=2&murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.worldofwatches.com%2Fdetail.asp%3Fiq%3D1%26bo_products_id%3D0%26bo_products_variance_id%3D165482%26promotion_code%3DWMP7071071013141418910165482"><img src="http://www.dailycrazydeals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/casio.png" alt="img11"><h4>test</h4></a>
<hr width="130%" noshade>
   </li>
</td>
</tr>   

                <tr>
                    <td>WAS:</td>
                    <td class="strikethrough">$179.95</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>YOU SAVE:<hr width="130%" noshade></td>
                    <td>$40.00<hr width="100%" noshade></td>
                </tr>
<tr>
<td>$139.95</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: do u want to remove border that comes above the "Shoes" menu ?

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out the following line

```
border-top: 5px solid #333333;
```

In your itemSlider/css/style.css file
use

```
.mi-slider nav {

    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 400px;
}
```

instead

```
.mi-slider nav {
    border-top: 5px solid #333333;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 400px;
}
```